# NO_CRASH_STACK + 0 [Xcode 10.1] Crash

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, twitter, crash

Im experiencing an error in my app affecting almost 80% of my active users.

It seems it has something to do with the thread

```
`com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer`
```

but I haven't been able to track it down, the worst thing of all is that I don't even know when this crash occurs, my guess is that it happens when the app is launching in the DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. :/

Hope you can help me out, I am new to this crash tracking thing.

Here is the crash log.

```
Incident Identifier: F627A1C2-A28A-4200-8920-1F77D3C0855C
CrashReporter Key:   88dbf413f263228712a90868f4c08e9d59a715f8
Hardware Model:      iPhone10,4
Process:             <APP_NAME> [1285]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/<APP_NAME>.app/<APP_NAME>
Identifier:          xxx.xxxxxxxx.<APP_NAME>
Version:             34 (4.0.0)
AppStoreTools:       10B63
AppVariant:          1:iPhone10,4:12
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           xxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx [677]


Date/Time:           2018-12-16 16:41:34.1689 -0600
Launch Time:         2018-12-16 15:52:00.9225 -0600
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.1 (16B92)
Baseband Version:    2.01.07
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000f262e3bc0
VM Region Info: 0xf262e3bc0 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 53790784449  
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_NANO            0000000280000000-00000002a0000000 [512.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--->  
      UNUSED SPACE AT END

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [1285]
Triggered by Thread:  10

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000203c3bed0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000203c3b3a8 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000020403fbc4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236 (CFRunLoop.c:2615)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000020403aa60 __CFRunLoopRun + 1396 (CFRunLoop.c:2971)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000020403a1cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
5   GraphicsServices                0x00000002062b1584 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
6   UIKitCore                       0x000000023127d054 UIApplicationMain + 212 (UIApplication.m:4347)
7   <APP_NAME>                          0x0000000104ae4548 main + 17736 (AppDelegate.swift:22)
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000203afabb4 start + 4

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000203c3bed0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000203c3b3a8 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000020403fbc4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236 (CFRunLoop.c:2615)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000020403aa60 __CFRunLoopRun + 1396 (CFRunLoop.c:2971)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000020403a1cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
5   Foundation                      0x0000000204a2f404 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300 (NSRunLoop.m:367)
6   Foundation                      0x0000000204a2f2b0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 148 (NSRunLoop.m:411)
7   UIKitCore                       0x000000023136a808 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136 (UIEventFetcher.m:603)
8   Foundation                      0x0000000204b621ac __NSThread__start__ + 1040 (NSThread.m:1175)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccb2ac _pthread_body + 128 (pthread.c:857)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccb20c _pthread_start + 48 (pthread.c:884)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccecf4 thread_start + 4

Thread 2 name:  com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000203c3bed0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000203c3b3a8 mach_msg + 72
2   <APP_NAME>                          0x0000000104f0c490 CLSMachExceptionServer + 952
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccb2ac _pthread_body + 128
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccb20c _pthread_start + 48
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccecf4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000203c3bed0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000203c3b3a8 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000020403fbc4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236 (CFRunLoop.c:2615)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000020403aa60 __CFRunLoopRun + 1396 (CFRunLoop.c:2971)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000020403a1cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000020465b834 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 212 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1365)
6   Foundation                      0x0000000204b621ac __NSThread__start__ + 1040 (NSThread.m:1175)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccb2ac _pthread_body + 128 (pthread.c:857)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccb20c _pthread_start + 48 (pthread.c:884)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccecf4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccece8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccece8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccece8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccece8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x0000000203c80c74 nanov2_allocate_from_block$VARIANT$armv81 + 220
1   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x0000000203c80040 nanov2_allocate$VARIANT$armv81 + 140
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x0000000203c80040 nanov2_allocate$VARIANT$armv81 + 140
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x0000000203c80540 nanov2_calloc$VARIANT$armv81 + 136
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x0000000203c8db74 malloc_zone_calloc + 140 (malloc.c:1475)
5   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x0000000203c8e3fc calloc + 40 (malloc.c:1731)
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000203290554 class_createInstance + 72 (objc-runtime-new.mm:0)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000203ae9ad8 _os_object_alloc_realized + 40 (object.m:55)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000203ae3af4 dispatch_data_create_concat$VARIANT$armv81 + 164 (data.c:118)
9   CFNetwork                       0x00000002048b8ffc invocation function for block in ConnectionProtocolReadInner(nw_protocol*, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, long long, void (dispatch_data_s*, CFStreamError) block_pointer, void (nw_frame_array_s*, CFStreamError) block_pointer) + 152 (ConnectionProtocol.cpp:771)
10  libnetwork.dylib                0x00000002050d3474 nw_frame_array_foreach + 48 (frame_internal.h:999)
11  CFNetwork                       0x00000002048b64ac ConnectionProtocolReadInner(nw_protocol*, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, long long, void (dispatch_data_s*, CFStreamError) block_pointer, void (nw_frame_array_s*, CFStreamError) block_pointer) + 408 (ConnectionProtocol.cpp:755)
12  CFNetwork                       0x00000002048b6264 ConnectionProtocolServiceReads(nw_protocol*) + 380 (ConnectionProtocol.cpp:658)
13  CFNetwork                       0x00000002048b7270 ConnectionProtocolInputAvailable(nw_protocol*, nw_protocol*) + 64 (ConnectionProtocol.cpp:964)
14  libboringssl.dylib              0x0000000204f34ac8 nw_boringssl_read + 532 (protocol_boringssl.m:1177)
15  libboringssl.dylib              0x0000000204f362a4 nw_protocol_boringssl_input_available + 120 (protocol_boringssl.m:1218)
16  libusrtcp.dylib                 0x00000002053d8e9c nw_protocol_tcp_wake_read + 484 (protocol_tcp.c:269)
17  libusrtcp.dylib                 0x00000002053c9774 nw_protocol_tcp_input_flush + 100 (user_north.c:40)
18  libnetwork.dylib                0x0000000205167474 nw_channel_add_input_frames + 4184 (channel.c:1096)
19  libnetwork.dylib                0x00000002051663b8 nw_channel_update_input_source + 136 (channel.c:1138)
20  libnetwork.dylib                0x0000000205165c08 __nw_channel_create_block_invoke.21 + 52 (channel.c:1960)
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000203aea484 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:511)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000203ac0e14 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$armv81 + 404 (inline_internal.h:2441)
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000203ad0ab4 _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 1704 (source.c:568)
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000203ac6d70 _dispatch_workloop_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 1892 (inline_internal.h:2482)
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000203acdf14 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 584 (queue.c:5889)
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccc0dc _pthread_wqthread + 312 (pthread.c:2363)
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccecec start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccece8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10 name:
Thread 10 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000203298d70 objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreData                        0x0000000206c17754 -[_PFArray dealloc] + 100 (_PFArray.m:379)
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000020329b38c (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 676 (NSObject.mm:1605)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000203aea464 _dispatch_last_resort_autorelease_pool_pop + 40 (object.m:488)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000203accddc _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1080 (queue.c:6049)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000203acd35c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 116 (queue.c:6072)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccc17c _pthread_wqthread + 472 (pthread.c:2353)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccecec start_wqthread + 4

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccece8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000280283bb0   x1: 0x00000002317c19b4   x2: 0x0000000000000001   x3: 0x0000000203c8019c
    x4: 0x000000014a514400   x5: 0x0000000000000012   x6: 0x000000023b9c4000   x7: 0x000000016b77e538
    x8: 0x0000000281685080   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000148860a00  x11: 0x0000002f0000003f
   x12: 0x0000000148860d40  x13: 0x0000a69f262e3bb0  x14: 0x000000000000004c  x15: 0x0000000080000000
   x16: 0x0000000f262e3bb0  x17: 0x0000000206c0f138  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000282fc8b70
   x20: 0x00000002317c19b4  x21: 0x000000000000000c  x22: 0x0000000000000020  x23: 0x0000000000000015
   x24: 0x0000000000000010  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016b77f0e0   fp: 0x000000016b77ea80   lr: 0x0000000206c17754
    sp: 0x000000016b77ea40   pc: 0x0000000203298d70 cpsr: 0x20000000
```

AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

        GeoBasedManager.instance.setCountry()
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        NotificationManager.shared.retrievePushNotifications()
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        SwiftDate.defaultRegion = Region.local
        DropDown.startListeningToKeyboard()

return true
```

Comment: Can you please share how did you add Crashlytics to your project?

Comment: Can you please share this code in the question?

Comment: Done, added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thread `com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer` is a part of the Crashlytics reporting machinery. It is present in every report that Crashlytics generates, and is not related to your issue.

From your report, that `Triggered by Thread:  10` indicates which thread is at fault. From that, we can see that you've got what looks like a classic over-release.

```
Thread 10 name:
Thread 10 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000203298d70 objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreData                        0x0000000206c17754 -[_PFArray dealloc] + 100 (_PFArray.m:379)
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000020329b38c (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 676 (NSObject.mm:1605)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000203aea464 _dispatch_last_resort_autorelease_pool_pop + 40 (object.m:488)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000203accddc _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1080 (queue.c:6049)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000203acd35c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 116 (queue.c:6072)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccc17c _pthread_wqthread + 472 (pthread.c:2353)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000203ccecec start_wqthread + 4
```

From frame 2 and 3, you can see that the system is cleaning up auto-released objects, from what looks like an internal dispatch queue. In there is an object that has already been deallocated, but is now being released again.

This kinds of bugs can manifest themselves in a variety of different-looking crashes. They can be hard to debug. As you are seeing, it is very hard to determine where the actual over-release occurred. Fortunately, Apple provides a few tools that can help. Check out the Zombies feature of Instruments. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I tried the zombies profiling tool. but not luck so far.
It is also weird that in thread 10 frame 1 it says "CoreData". I'm not using CoreData at all in my app.